# Temp conversion: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, list, integer, typeerror, temp

Want it to be able to convert both ways, if Celsius then it converts to Fahrenheit and vice versa. I'm fresh outta the box when it comes to Python, and this is part of one of my classes. Using higher order functions and learning how to implement them.

```
    def tConvert(x,y = "C"):
        loop = len(x)
        while loop > 0:
            if y == "C":
                result = float(round((9 * x) / 5 + 32))
            else:
                y == "C"
                result = float(round((x - 32) * 5 / 9))
                return result
```

```
 File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Python 12.py", line 8, in tConvert
    result = float(round((x - 32) * 5 / 9))
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'
```

Comment: It appears `x` is a list…

Comment: My main() passes a list of temperatures in either C or F to this helper function tConvert.  I need it to stay in list form but this problem has me stuck.

Comment: You appear to be wanting to loop over the list somehow, but you're not. `x` *is* the list, so you can't use `-` on it. You want `x[0]` or something of that sort. Perhaps `x[loop]`, but you're also not decrementing `loop` anywhere, so you'd have an infinite loop if it wasn't for your immediate `return`…

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is a list, then just run through the list converting one at a time.  And there's no need to round if you're keeping the result as a float.

```
    def tConvert(x,y = "C"):
        result = []
        for temp in x:
            if y == "C":
                result.append( 9 * temp / 5 + 32)
            else:
                result.append( (temp - 32) * 5 / 9)
        return result
```